# inserting an x in between a predrawn base

Tags: java

I want to initialize an x between the first | | and move it as users input left, right, down, up. I think I just mostly need help with putting the x there in the first place. Can probably figure out the rest based on the answer.

```
public class dimensions {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Select the size of the world widthxheight: ");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
         String input = sc.nextLine();
         String[] parts = input.split("x");
         String part1 = parts[0];
         String part2 = parts[1];
         int sx = 1;
         int sy = 0;
         int width = Integer.parseInt(part1);
         int height = Integer.parseInt(part2);
         for (int h = height - 1; h >= 0; h--) {
             for (int w = width - 1; w >= 0; w--) {
                 if (w == width - 1) {
                     System.out.print("| |");
                 } else {
                     System.out.print(" |");
                 }
             }
             System.out.print("\n");
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the user to be able to move over the map, by printing the map each time the user changes position? And you want the start to be at the top-left, right?

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry for being unclear. I think I'll be able to figure it out now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `X` in the first field with the following code:

```
    [...]

    int width = Integer.parseInt(part1);
    int height = Integer.parseInt(part2);

    int playerPosX = 0;
    int playerPosY = 0;

    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            String temp = " |";
            if (w == 0) {
                temp = "| |";
            }
            if (playerPosX == w && playerPosY == h) {
                temp = temp.replace(' ', 'X');
            }
            System.out.print(temp);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

You can also specify the position of the player, respectively the position of the `X` with the variables `playerPosX` and `playerPosY`.

BUT, moving the player without drawing the whole map after each move is not possible, because `System.out` is technically a stream and it's not possible to manipulate data which was already sent to the stream.

I would suggest that you create your own window in which you add a text field and print the map on that.

[Tutorial for creating Swing windows.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

[Tutorial for creating text areas.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)